# Updating Cloudant database using Java

Tags: java, cloudant, nosql

Was wondering if it possible to write code in Java that will update the entries in my Cloudant database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  Its possible to write JAVA code to update entries / documents in Cloudant database.  You need to use the java-cloudant driver.  Please have a look at the following project on github.

https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant

Even otherwise you can also write JAVA code to make REST calls ( POST / PUT ) etc to the Cloudant stores to directly update the documents.

Thanks,
Ranjan

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Where can I find this java-cloudant driver?

Comment: You can get the cloudant-client-1.0.1.jar from Maven repository  or from Gradle.  Here is the link    http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/1.0.1   .  Also remember to get the dependent jars too.

Comment: Hi,  Were you able to download the jars and create java programs for updating cloudant docs ? In that case can you please accept this as answer. Please let me know if you are facing any issues with the java-cloudant driver.